# can not update using JSP

Tags: java, jsp

can you help me resolve my problem?I use JSP to update but no action be occurred(insert and delete be OK).For example,I update cname from ASUS to SONY but when click on Update button,cname still be ASUS.
note that cid is auto_increment

Here is update method in DAO

```
public int updateComputer(Computer com) {
    int n = 0;
    try {
        String sql = "UPDATE Computer SET cname=?, quantity=?, price=?,functions=? where cid=?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        // Parameters start with 1
        preparedStatement.setString(1, com.getCname());
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, com.getQuantity());
        preparedStatement.setDouble(3, com.getPrice());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, com.getFunc());
        n = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ComputerDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return n;
}
```

here is updateComputer.jsp

```html
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="dao.ComputerDAO"%>
<%@page import="entity.Computer"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            ComputerDAO comDAO = new ComputerDAO();
            String cid = request.getParameter("cid");
            ResultSet rs = comDAO.getData("Select * from Computer where cid=" + Integer.parseInt(cid));
            Computer com = new Computer();
            if (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String cname = rs.getString(2).trim();
                int quan = rs.getInt(3);
                double price = rs.getDouble(4);
                String func = rs.getString(5).trim();
                com = new Computer(id, cname, quan, price, func);
            }
%>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="ProcessUpdateComputer.jsp">
            <table width="400" height="252" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <caption>
                    <h2>Update Computer</h2>
                </caption>
                <tr>
                    <th width="29%" align="left" scope="row">Computer ID</th>
                    <td width="71%">
                        <input type="text" name="cid" id="cid" disabled="" value="<%= com.getCid()%>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th width="29%" align="left" scope="row">Computer Name</th>
                    <td width="71%">
                        <input type="text" name="cname" id="cname" value="<%=com.getCname()%>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left" scope="row">Quantity</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<%=com.getQuantity()%>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left" scope="row">Price</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="<%= com.getPrice()%>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left" scope="row">Functions</th>
                    <td>
                        <!--<input type="text" name="functions" id="functions" value="<%=com.getFunc()%>"></td>-->
                        <textarea name="functions" rows="8" id="functions" value="<%=com.getFunc()%>"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="right" scope="row"></th>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Update">
                        <input type="hidden" name="service" id="service" value="<%= cid%>"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p align="center"><a href="ListComputer.jsp">View Computer List</a></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is ProcessUpdateComputer.jsp

```html
<%@page import="entity.Computer"%>
<%@page import="dao.ComputerDAO"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            ComputerDAO dao = new ComputerDAO();
            String cname = request.getParameter("cname");
            String quan = request.getParameter("quantity");
            String price = request.getParameter("price");
            String func = request.getParameter("functions");
            
            int uquan = Integer.parseInt(quan);
            double uprice = Double.parseDouble(price);

            Computer com = new Computer(0, cname, uquan, uprice, func);
            int i = dao.updateComputer(com);
            if (i > 0) {
                out.println("updated");
            }

        %>
        <p><a href="ListComputer.jsp">View Computer List</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where you are calling updateComputer method?

Comment: in ProcessUpdateComputer.jsp I called dao.updateComputer(com)

Answer (score 0):

Here you're missing the fifth parameter, the cid:

```
 String sql = "UPDATE Computer SET cname=?, quantity=?, price=?,functions=? where cid=?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    // Parameters start with 1
    preparedStatement.setString(1, com.getCname());
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, com.getQuantity());
    preparedStatement.setDouble(3, com.getPrice());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, com.getFunc());

    preparedStatement.setString(5, com.getId());

    n = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Here is not clear what you want to do, are you always trying to update the computer with cid=0?

```
 Computer com = new Computer(0, cname, uquan, uprice, func);
 int i = dao.updateComputer(com);
```

You'll probably want to retrieve the cid from the request, like the other params

```
  String cid = request.getParameter("cid");
```

Comment: Firstly,I try with Computer com = new Computer(Integer.parseInt(cid), cname, uquan, uprice, func); but there is error with code line when compile

Comment: And my cid is auto_increment

Comment: auto_increment means that id is assigned from the db during inserts, it has nothing to do with updates. In updates you have to specify the id, otherwise which record are you updating?

Comment: error in Computer com = new Computer(Integer.parseInt(cid), cname, uquan, uprice, func); in ProcessUpdateComputer.jsp

Comment: but if I update with a specific ID then it works well :(